# CISCO WebDialer API, The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke

Tags: soap, wsdl, cisco

I'm trying to use Cisco WebDialer API but have a few issues with it:

When I try to send the following SOAP request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WD70">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <urn:makeCallSoap soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <in0 xsi:type="urn:Credential">
             <userID xsi:type="xsd:string">user******</userID>
             <password xsi:type="xsd:string">pass*****</password>
          </in0>
          <in1 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1234</in1>
          <in2 xsi:type="urn:UserProfile">
             <user xsi:type="xsd:string">wd</user>
             <deviceName xsi:type="xsd:string">SEP001558C8970F</deviceName>
             <lineNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">901234565</lineNumber>
             <supportEM xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</supportEM>
             <locale xsi:type="xsd:string">English</locale>
             <dontAutoClose xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</dontAutoClose>
             <dontShowCallConf xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</dontShowCallConf>
          </in2>
       </urn:makeCallSoap>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

to `https://SERVER:PORT/webdialer/services/WebdialerSoapService70` I got the following error:

```
The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke!  targetService is WebdialerSoapService70
```

When I try to access directly https:///webdialer/services/WebdialerSoapService70 via browser I get the following message:

```
AXIS error
No service is available at this URL
```

My question is what is wrong? Do I miss something in my request or required service isn't running? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to my colleague I've got the answer. You need to go to the following link:

```
https://SERVER:PORT/webdialer/services
```

And you'll see list of all working services and links to them. In my case right link was:

```
https://SERVER:PORT/webdialer/services/WebdialerSoapService
```

After I've changed it everything begin to work. And yes, when you open right link in browser you have to get the following message:

```
WebdialerSoapService
Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...
```